# SOAP - Remaining free space

Tags: rest, soap, space-usage

Is there any way how to find out how much free space is remaing in the whole Sharepoint site? I need to find it out by SOAP interface.

Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if memory servers me correct there is no webservice that would do what your asking for!

you need to make a custom webservice and within the code add,

```
public string getWarninglevel(string url)
{
      using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(url))
      {
       //the warning level when reached
       return siteCollection.Quota.StorageWarningLevel.ToString();
      }
}

public string getMaxlevel(string url)
{
      using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(url))
      {
       //your max storage you can have
       siteCollection.Quota.StorageMaximumLevel.ToString();
      }
}

public string getCurrentlevel(string url)
{
      using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(url))
      {
       //your total storage avaiable
       return siteCollection.Usage.Storage.ToString();
      }
}
```

im returning string for simplicity ;)

to make a webservice either follow any of these:

http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2010/04/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010_17.html

or

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/07/16/writing-and-hosting-a-web-service-in-the-sharepoint-2010-demo-virtual-machine.aspx

or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040(v=office.14).aspx

within the browser when you do vti_bin/SiteQuto.asmx you would/should have those three methods to use. The last one is the one you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you. This help me a lot. It is really a pity, that there is no such webservice ... but what can I do ... I will follow your advices. Thank you.

Comment: no problem happy to help! for some reason admin stuff in 2010 is lacking but it gets better in 2013